# Extract Bricklink or Brickowl parts list from LDD (on OS X)

Tags: ldd, bricklink, replacement-parts, brickowl

I've got some models .lxf and I'd like to order the parts. Is there a way to extract that information from LDD on OS X? All the solutions I have seen so far go via a Windows application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bricklink Wanted List Uploader

It is very simple to upload a parts list to Bricklink. You can directly upload your LDD file through the [Bricklink wanted page uploader](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/wanted/upload.page).

[image]

The wanted list uploader supports the these four file types:

- **LEGO Digital Designer (.lxf)**
- BrickStock/Brickstore (.bsx)
- LDraw (.ldr)
- Stud.io (.io)

---

If the Bricklink uploader doesn't work, you can also use LDD also lets you export a list of parts from within the application.

In LEGO Digital Designer, open your model. Go to File > Export BOM (Ctrl + B) to save a spreadsheet/zip copy of all the parts used in your model.

The file will include information include part name, ID, colour, quantity as well as a thumbnail photo of each piece.

[image]